Does postgres fulltext search support wildcard matches similiar to LIKE?
Does postgres fulltext search support searches that can mimick matches with LIKE or ILIKE (case insenstivie)?
SELECT * FROM Users  WHERE firstname ILIKE 'KE%' 
or a prefix `ILIKE '%EN'
Using fulltext search currently at it seems it doesn't support partial matches, it has to be the complete word or number for it to match.
My query:
WHERE u.fts_search_ts && to_tsquery('KE:*')
My index was created like this:
ALTER TABLE Users
ADD COLUMN fts_search_ts tsvector
    GENERATED ALWAYS AS (to_tsvector('english',  
        coalesce(firstname, '') || ' ' || 
        coalesce(account_number, '') )
    ) STORED;


Did you look what the documentation says about that? Full-text search can only match whole (stemmed) words or prefixes of these.

Fulltext search is very different from LIKE/ILIKE, you just can't compare the two. And what you describe as an index, is actually a generated column. You might want to index that column, but that's a different/additional database object.

Buy the way, names are not a good subject for full text search: Not enough text. Most likely you want the extension pg_trgm. This has also support for reading an index when using ILIKE: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/pgtrgm.html#PGTRGM-INDEX

Prefix matching works as documented if you do it correctly.  && is the AND-concatenation operator, not the matching operator, so you aren't doing it correctly.

It seems like you are trying to do a live search (like autocomplete) as a user types which means you end up with partial strings (prefix / substring). LIKE/ILIKE might be you best option in that case, whereas full text search with ts vectors is better for full keyword search... Checkout some comparisons of search types for pros and cons of either method.

Try
WHERE u.fts_search_ts @@ to_tsquery('KE:*')
instead of
WHERE u.fts_search_ts && to_tsquery('KE:*')
Then it should work.
